# Should I add how many work contract renewals I had in previous jobs when writing my CV?

Tags: resume, job-search

I was updating my CV while this came to my mind.

Let's say that person A worked for a total of 1 year for 2 different employers.
Each work contract he had lasted 6 months.

Now let's say person B also worked for a total of 1 year always for 2 different employers but had many different work contract: 3 work contracts from the former employer and 2 work contracts from the latter.

When applying for a new job, does B have more possibilities to get the job?

And so, **Should I add how many work contract renewals I had in previous jobs when writing my CV?**

Comment: What do you mean with "work contract"? Do you mean a contract with the employer? Or do you mean being contracted out (seconded) to a third party by your employer?

Comment: I mean a contract with the employer. Sorry, I'm just not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CV (resume) should be short and to the point, describing where you worked, which time period and - most importantly - what you did there.

Information about the number of contracts you had with an employer in the period you worked there is at best irrelevant information which detracts attention from the more important things in your CV, and at worst an immediate reason for rejection.

Having a number of short term contracts with the same employer can easily be seen as you being a bad employee that has been given a second or third chance, by not giving a longer term (or even permanent) contract, but just another short (or shorter) term extension.

Just to be clear: even including this information when you had a single contract for the entire period would raise my eyebrows, and I'd wonder why you felt the need to include it.